# Access selected text and URL from browser's share intent

Tags: android, android-intent

In the Android stock browser, Chrome and most other browser apps, selecting text on a page displays a contextual ActionBar. Besides text tools, it contains a share functionality which sends the text selection to other apps, probably using `sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Selected text")`.

My question: can apps that have registered for that send intent (using an `<intent-filter/>`) access the URL of the website that the text was extracted from? In other words, is the URL passed as an `EXTRA_...` in the intent?

Of course one could write a test app and check for all passed extras listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_ALARM_COUNT). But I was hoping for some insights or an alternative approach to send selected text *and* the URL from the browser (at least from the stock browser) to another app.
This would be a very useful feature, e.g. to share a quote in a social networking app while automatically linking the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question: can apps that have registered for that send intent (using an ) access the URL of the website that the text was extracted from? In other words, is the URL passed as an EXTRA_... in the intent?

- I am aware of no documented and supported extras beyond `EXTRA_TEXT` for any browser
- The source code of the AOSP Browser app does not show anything being added to the `Intent` beyond `EXTRA_TEXT`
- You are welcome to dump the `Intent` extras `Bundle` and examine them for any given browser you want, to see what is included, though whether undocumented extras will be available in the future is not guaranteed

Comment: Thank you for your farsighted answer. Just to be sure, I have created a small test app, registered for the intent and shared some text from the stock and Chrome browser. In both cases, the received bundle only contained `android.intent.extra.TEXT` with the selected text, as you said.